How to connect to H2 database through TCP using h2go package?
I have docker container with H2 database, I can connect to it using "Database" IDE feature, also can ping container host using DNS name inside my server container.
I'm using github.com/jmrobles/h2go package as database driver, so i tried (i deleted some unnessecary code):
package service

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/jmrobles/h2go"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func (s *DataSourceService) ConnectToH2Db(dbHost, dbUsername, dbPassword, dbName string, dbPort int) (*sqlx.DB, error) {
    connectionData := fmt.Sprintf("h2://%v:%v@%v:%v/%v", dbUsername, dbPassword, dbHost, dbPort, dbName)
    logrus.Info(connectionData)
    conn, err := sqlx.Open("h2", connectionData)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Info("open")
        return nil, err
    }
    if err = conn.Ping(); err != nil {
        logrus.Info("ping")
        return nil, err
    }
    return conn, nil
}

When trying to connect i got driver: bad connection and logrus printed open.
Thanks in advance for the answer.
I also tried to use postgres driver
Here my code:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("started")
    username := "242440313243303331324a282975402148443041534a4430448fcaad801291b2a314895c683585be5263a6d9852473771474dff653f1c278d6"
    password := "242440313243303331324a282975402148443041534a4430448fcaad801291b2a314895c683585be5263a6d9852473771474dff653f1c278d6"
    host := "localhost"
    port := "7899"
    dbname := "NEWDB1"
    connectionData := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%v:%v@%v:%v/%v?sslmode=disable", username, password, host, port, dbname)
    //connectionData := fmt.Sprintf("host=%v port=%v user=%v password=%v dbname=%v sslmode=disable",
    //  host, port, username, password, dbname)
    conn, err := sqlx.Open("postgres", connectionData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("connected to database")
    if err = conn.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("ping")
    if err = conn.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("close")
}

But it gives me:
2024/06/05 16:30:41 started
connected to database
2024/06/05 16:30:41 runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:-4]


Have you tried the minimal in-memory setup as documented on the github page to see if you can at least get that working? I must say that the combination of the "this is highly experimental" plus the fact that the code hasn't been touched for 4 years does not inspire a whole lot of faith in this driver for me.

@Gimby Yes, it works well, you're most probably right, but why doesn't it work with postgres driver? Speaking about postgres driver, I also tried to use shorter username and password, but had the same error

Using a driver for a different database to connect to H2 also does not inspire a lot of faith in me, it's just a hack to be honest that will be a ticking timebomb. Practically given what I've seen so far, I would simply not use H2 in combination with Go. it's a recipe for the hurting never stopping.

Yeah, it's the reason why i moved to postgres in my project. But maybe someone knows how to do that

Postgres was quite a move. There are options for embedded (SQL) databases is go other than the (as @Gimby pointed out correctly) rather esoteric h2 driver.

Testsetup
The code is available at https://github.com/mwmahlberg/go-database-78579085
I checked your revised code with a docker-compose as follows:
.
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── env
├── env-long
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── main.go

Below you will find their contents, README.md, LICENSE (WTFPL), go.mod, go.sum skipped for brevity.
Dockerfile
FROM golang:1.22-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go build -o main .
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/main" ]

docker-compose.yaml
volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - 7899:5432
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "${USERNAME:-test}"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
      start_interval: 5s
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: NEWDB1
      POSTGRES_USER: ${USERNAME:-test}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PASSWORD:-test}
  app:
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: app:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command:
      - "-host=postgres"
      - "-port=5432"
      - "-username=${USERNAME:-test}"
      - "-password=${PASSWORD:-test}"

env
USERNAME=leiZie4oogha0Uoth8Johphi0wi6apeiCh8oosheithoDohs0airaeghiePiw5r
PASSWORD=leiZie4oogha0Uoth8Johphi0wi6apeiCh8oosheithoDohs0airaeghiePiw5r

env-long
PASSWORD=242440313243303331324a282975402148443041534a4430448fcaad801291b2a314895c683585be5263a6d9852473771474dff653f1c278d6
USERNAME=242440313243303331324a282975402148443041534a4430448fcaad801291b2a314895c683585be5263a6d9852473771474dff653f1c278d6

main.go
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var (
    host     string
    port     int
    dbname   string
    username string
    password string
)

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&host, "host", "localhost", "host")
    flag.IntVar(&port, "port", 7899, "port")
    flag.StringVar(&dbname, "dbname", "NEWDB1", "dbname")
    flag.StringVar(&username, "username", "", "username")
    flag.StringVar(&password, "password", "", "password")
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.Println("started")
    connectionData := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%v:%v@%v:%v/%v?sslmode=disable", username, password, host, port, dbname)
    conn, err := sqlx.Open("postgres", connectionData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("connected to database")
    if err = conn.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("ping")
    if err = conn.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("close")
}

Results
During startup of docker compose --env-file env-long up, I get the following error:
postgres-1  | 2024-06-09 14:42:28.775 UTC [40] FATAL:  identifier too long at character 72
postgres-1  | 2024-06-09 14:42:28.775 UTC [40] DETAIL:  Identifier must be less than 64 characters.
postgres-1  | 2024-06-09 14:42:28.775 UTC [40] STATEMENT:  
postgres-1  |   UPDATE pg_class   SET relacl = (SELECT array_agg(a.acl) FROM  (SELECT E'=r/"242440313243303331324a282975402148443041534a4430448fcaad801291b2a314895c683585be5263a6d9852473771474dff653f1c278d6"' as acl   UNION SELECT unnest(pg_catalog.acldefault(    CASE WHEN relkind = 'S' THEN 's'          ELSE 'r' END::"char",10::oid)) ) as a)   WHERE relkind IN ('r', 'v', 'm', 'S')  AND relacl IS NULL;
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | child process exited with exit code 1

When I try to manually create said user, I get the following error:
postgres=# CREATE USER 242440313243303331324a282975402148443041534a4430448fcaad801291b2a314895c683585be5263a6d9852473771474dff653f1c278d6 WITH PASSWORD '242440313243303331324a282975402148443041534a4430448fcaad801291b2a314895c683585be5263a6d9852473771474dff653f1c278d6';
ERROR:  trailing junk after numeric literal at or near "242440313243303331324a"
LINE 1: CREATE USER 242440313243303331324a282975402148443041534a4430...

Setting the username to a 63 long string works as expected:
postgres=# CREATE USER leiZie4oogha0Uoth8Johphi0wi6apeiCh8oosheithoDohs0airaeghiePiw5r WITH PASSWORD 'leiZie4oogha0Uoth8Johphi0wi6apeiCh8oosheithoDohs0airaeghiePiw5r';
CREATE ROLE

Running docker compose --env-file env up after resetting the compose environment with docker compose down --volumes results in:
app-1       | 2024/06/09 14:46:23 started
app-1       | connected to database
app-1       | 2024/06/09 14:46:23 ping
app-1       | 2024/06/09 14:46:23 close

Conclusion
The problem is not in the go code, but in the database setup. Also, I never ever got the error runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:-4]. I assume there is code missing in your example.

Thanks for the answer, it's really useful to know max length of the credentials data, but the question was about how to connect to H2 database, but you're trying to connect to Postgres

@parnishkka Maybe you should not move goalposts in your question, then.

I didn't move anything, re-read the question and find me the place where I would say that I couldn't connect to the Postgres database

Well, as you see fit. BTW, welcome to SO. I am sure your attitude will take you a long way here.
